# SQLite's Response To Non-Character Entries

Tags: sql, sqlite

This question regards SQL, specifically SQLite's implementation.

I have created a database. In this database is a table called "Items". It has the fields:

- PLU/EAN
- Name
- Price
- Type

All types are varchar(255) except Price, which is numeric(10, 2).
Now comes the core of the question:
What is the difference between the following statements and how is the second one appropriately used?
1. `insert into items values (7340011403777, upper("orange soda"), 10.90, "Consumable");`
2. `insert into items values (7340011403777, upper("orange soda"), 10.90, Consumable);`

The first statement does what is expected: adds the tuple into the database (correct wording (tuple)?).

On the second version it states:

> Error: no such column: Consumable

Does this imply there is a method to designate a column from somewhere here? If defined, how will such a syntax work? Is this generally standardized SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's in this case no standard way to name a table or table expression to get a column named in `VALUES` from.

The reason you're getting the message is that `VALUES` takes a number of expressions as parameters, and an unquoted name in an expression generally resolves to a column name. Since the column name cannot be found anywhere, you're getting your error message.

To insert using values from a column name in another table, you can't use a values clause but can insert straight from a `SELECT`;

```
INSERT INTO dest SELECT id, value*2 FROM source;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/bb35c/2).

As a side note, string literals should be single quoted, otherwise SQLite will try to find a column name with the quoted name before using the string itself which can give strange results;

[An SQLfiddle showing the effect](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/35371/1). Note that the first select uses double quotes so it will compare the column `value` with itself, giving the wrong results, while the single quoted version will compare the column `value` with the string `'value'`, giving the correct result.

Comment: I wonder about the generality of SQL's syntax. Could it be said that the part `SELECT id, value*2 FROM source` is evaluated to be an "object"? Then, we obtain: `INSERT INTO dest object`. I tend to find such rules in other languages but I'm having the slightest trouble with SQL. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is standard SQL syntax error. The column Type is a Varchar(255). Hence it expects a string value.

The query:

```
2. insert into items values (7340011403777, upper("orange soda"), 10.90, Consumable);
```

implies that Consumables is a column Database object rather than a String Literal.

String Literals should always be quoted as "Consumable".